# Why do trailing whitespaces in the field of sql-query produces "wrong" result?

Tags: mysql

Suppose, we have a test table in MySql:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
    `_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `testfield` TEXT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

it contains a single row:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`testfield`) VALUES ('testValue');
```

Then when I do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `testField` = 'testValue';
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `testField` = 'testValue ';
```

or even this:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE `testField` = 'testValue  ';
```

I always receive the same result, and it is this single row, but I want this row only in first case.

Why mysql truncate blank spaces at the end of `'testVaue '`? And the main question, what should I do to eliminate such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When MySQL compares strings it trims all trailing spaces (`'x     ' = 'x'` is true).
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495692/mysql-comparison-operator-spaces) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why exactly it trims the WHERE (what's the point of it?). It has probably to do with binary stuff etc., since you can fix it by making your `TEXT` field binary (`BLOB`).

Answer (score 1):

It's documented behavior: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5412. TEXT fields are treated the same as CHAR/VARCHAR for comparison purposes.