# Mysql like operator didn't find a match

Tags: mysql, sql, match, whitespace, sql-like

I have to search in database some name.
If I write

`LIKE '%Alex Maxim%'` - success.

If I write:

`LIKE '% Alex Maxim%'` - null.

I think is from the first white spaces(`'% Al...'`).

How can I do this ?

Comment: what are you expecting to get?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495692/mysql-comparison-operator-spaces)

Comment: If the first one work, why the second one?

Answer (score 2):

Remove whitespaces using [**TRIM()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-trim-function.php) string function

```
LIKE CONCAT('%',TRIM(' Alex Maxim'),'%')
```

If you want to remove only leading whitespace then use [**LTRIM()**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-ltrim-function.php) function

```
LIKE CONCAT('%',LTRIM(' Alex Maxim'),'%')
```

Comment: If I use trim I eliminated the all whitespaces.I need just the whitespace before ' Alex Maxim '